# trying to make Google maps work with IOS emulator in React native

Tags: xcode, google-maps, react-native, frontend

while trying to make Google map work on my IOS simulator using React native, I've received an error saying that Airgooglemaps directory must be added to Xcode.

[image]

And so after doing some research, I have been modifying files on my Xcode project and stumbled upon this error file building the project. Can anyone please help, thank you.

Apple Mach-O Linker Error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the library?

```
react-native link react-native-maps
```

Comment: Yup I think its a duplicate issue though